# want to build an ANT-Java project from another Java project

Tags: java, ant

I have two projects:

project  A: (Java) &

project  B: (ANT-Java)

I want to build project B from project A.
Actually Project A feeds a file to project B.
please suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: If you depend on file why not just select a common location and take it from there and if its not there then just fail the build?

Comment: ok but to achieve this I have to run both the projects once and want to to automate it. That is when I execute Project A it will feed the File to Project B and build it automatically

Comment: You can use standard Java Runtime to call external programms like the Ant command. Or more comfortable you can use: apache commons exec http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/

Comment: @ Stefan: The project is ANT based I can't change it. I have to use the same

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call ANT from Java without doing it by running an external command (calling ant), you could include ant runtime (ant.jar, download at [apache ant webpage](http://ant.apache.org/)) in your project A and execute any build target from your B project.

Example:

```
File buildFile = new File("build.xml");
Project p = new Project();
p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
p.init();
ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
helper.parse(p, buildFile);
p.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget());
```

You could check this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0502_gawor/0502_gawor.html#sec2b). It show how to manage return results and generated log. Hope this helps.